# .each() wait for iteration to finish before proceeding during async requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I have a form that allows for uploads to Dropbox via the API. It works by breaking the file up into chunks and sending those chunks up to Dropbox.

The chunks have to go up one after the other. So the first is sent and the second can not be sent until the first request is completed. Not to mention that different chunks have to go to different end points.

To this end I went with using syncronus requests in a .each() loop so that the process would wait before sending the next chunk.

My code below.

My problem is that when a large file is sent (150MB +) the browser begins to timneout and then the form is useless.

My question is, how can I make these requests asyncornus and still upload them in the right order and only send a chunk when the previous chunk has been sent.

```
knpv_chunked_upload(chunks){

var dropbox = this;

//Send each chunk to Dropbox
jQuery(dropbox.chunks).each(function(index, chunk){

    //This request is for the first chunk
    if (index == 0) {
        
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        xhr.open('POST', 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload_session/start', false); 
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer access_key');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Dropbox-API-Arg', JSON.stringify({close:false}));                 

    }

    //This request is for the middle chunks
    if (index >= 1 && index < dropbox.chunks.length - 1) {
        
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        xhr.open('POST', 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload_session/append_v2', false); 
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer access_key');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Dropbox-API-Arg', JSON.stringify({
                'close':false,
                'cursor': {
                    'session_id': dropbox.session_id,
                    'offset': dropbox.knpv_offset(index)
                }
            })
        );

    }

    //This request is for the last chunk
    if (index == dropbox.chunks.length - 1) {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        xhr.open('POST', 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload_session/finish', false);    
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer access_key');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Dropbox-API-Arg', JSON.stringify({
                'cursor': {
                    'session_id': dropbox.session_id,
                    'offset': dropbox.knpv_offset(index)
                },
                'commit': {
                    'path': dropbox.folderpath+'/'+chunk.name,
                    'mode': 'overwrite'
                }
            })
        );

    }

    //Send the chunk
    xhr.send(chunk);            
    

})

}
```

Comment: Rather than `.each` - send the next when the first has finished (in the first's .done callback (jquery))

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your help. Cold you perhaps add a basic code example below.

Comment: Here's an example that does what I was suggesting (albeit in a slightly more technical manner than I was suggesting): https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/blob/master/examples/javascript/upload/index.html